# The image keeps redirecting to allow url but I want it to stay in the page tab to see the image

Tags: php, html, facebook

I have a frustrating problem at hand. I need an image for my page tab application. And when I click on the image in the page tab, I want it to check if my account has used the application before. Now, I have an image in the code but it does not display out but rather it redirects to the application. How do I solve it?

```
<?php
header('P3P: CP="NOI ADM DEV PSAi COM NAV OUR OTRo STP IND DEM"');
include_once "config.php";
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION["visited"]))
{
    $_SESSION["visited"] = "yes";
?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<center>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function doReload() {
            top.location.href = "<?=$allow_url?>";
        }
    </script>
    <span id="continue" onclick="doReload()"><img src="photos/astronaut.png" alt=""/></span>
</center>
</body>
</html>
<?
}
else
{
    include_once "fbmain.php";
    include_once "mysqli.connect.php";
    include_once "fancybox.inc";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the short bit of code you have in your question, I don't see where you check that a user has auth'd your app, or even if there's any login to your app.  You may want to start getting into using the Facebook PHP SDK (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/) for authenticating the user so you can track them.